# In a table view can we give zoom in and zoom out effect?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ip, ipad

I want to zoom the table view to see the contents of the cell???i want to know whether it is possible???any kind of suggesstion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> **Important:** You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

From UIScrollView [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Edit,

May be you should implement something like and alertView when user taps on cell. Present an animated scroll view and there do the zooming.